# Kconfig: Why ``CONFIG_DRM_TTM`` is not displayed by kernel config tools?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

There is an option in `drivers/gpu/drm/Kconfig`:

```
   config DRM_TTM
           tristate
           depends on DRM
```

This option adds several functions used by DRM GPU drivers to manage videocard memory, so it depends on DRM as we can see.

It is also used by modules.

```
config DRM_RADEON
        tristate "ATI Radeon"
...
        select DRM_TTM
```

I have `DRM` enabled and when I enable one of these modules that `select`s it, I see this `CONFIG_DRM_TTM=y` is my `.config`
So far, so good.

But now I want to enable this option but disable all modules that use it (because I need it for 3rd party module which is not part of kernel source tree), so I enable only `DRM` but **I do not see this option** both in `menuconfig` and `xconfig`.

It seems that I can't enable this option manually, it could only be enabled by other module that `select`ing it.

From what I understand, this option must be displayed as `<>` because it is `tristate` and depends on `DRM`, so when I enable `DRM` I must see this option. But I do not.

How could it be? Is there any kind of "hidden" or "helper" option on Kconfig that can't be set manually, but only could be set by other options? Where can I read about it (except `mconf.c`` of course, because I assume my problem is too well known to read the source)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are “non-visible” configuration symbols which are set by `select` statements attached to other configuration entries. For example, `DRM_TTM` is selected by the GPU drivers which need it; it is a tristate because the options which depend on it are themselves tristates.

This is described briefly in [the `kconfig` language documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/kconfig-language.txt); the entry on `select` says

> In general use select only for non-visible symbols
>           (no prompts anywhere) and for symbols with no dependencies.
>           That will limit the usefulness but on the other hand avoid
>           the illegal configurations all over.

A configuration entry is invisible if it has no prompt, either following its type, or using an explicit `prompt` directive. To make the `DRM_TTM` configuration entry visible, give it a prompt:

```
config DRM_TTM
        tristate "TTM"
```

or

```
config DRM_TTM
        tristate
        prompt "TTM"
```

Comment: Thank you! So, is the following statement correct: "Option is invisible if at least one other option ``select``s it" ?

Comment: What is the best approach to enable this option if I do not need other modules? I can remove all ``select``s from different, but it does not look good.

Comment: It seems that the true reason of its invisibility is absence of name after "tristate". I will update my question with this info:)

Comment: Thanks, I’ve added that to the answer too, I’ll revert your question to its original form.